# Search words in two columns and copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my problem:

1. First, I need to find "Unit Name" in Column B.
2. If it found "Unit Name" it should look for "First Name:" in Column D and copy 5 cell right. ("Obama" in I10)
3. Paste the name "Obama" to Unit Name sheet. (Paste "Obama" to Sheet "1" A1)

I am new in coding therefore i don't know too much about it. I tried with some codes but it is not efficient.

Here is an image to show my problem.
[image: Here is an image to show my problem.]

```
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "Unit Name" Then
            m = 2
            m = i + 1
            n = i - 18

            If Range("D" & n).Value = "First Name:" Then
                m = Range("B" & m).Value + 1
                Range("H" & n).Copy
                Sheets(m).Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Where there are multiple names, do you want the second, third, etc. to fill in Sheet 1 A2, then A3, etc?

Comment: Also, do you really need to check for "Unit Name", why not just look for "First Name" in column D, and loop through that?  Also, do you want to copy the data in `I` column? Or `G`?

Comment: Yes we need to check Unit Name because the data is not goes with order. Each First Name should copy to different sheet in same cell. EX:                               
Unit Name: "1"/  First Name: "Obama" copy to Sheet "1" A1,                                                                
Unit Name: "2"/  First Name: "Trump" copy to Sheet "2" A1

Comment: @BruceWayne My main problem is I can"t limit the range when I searching for "First Name". If it finds "Unit Name" It should search just 20 cell in Column I for "First Name". Also not G it is I. I wrote it wrong sorry

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those integer variables, you can use a few `Range` variables instead:

```
Sub find_name()
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, altWS As Worksheet
Dim unitCel As Range, fNameCell As Range

Set mainWS = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'CHANGE AS NEEDED
Set altWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With mainWS
    Set unitCel = .Range("B:B").Find(What:="Unit Name")
    If Not unitCel Is Nothing Then
        Set fNameCell = .Range("D:D").Find(What:="First Name:").Offset(0, 5)
        altWS.Range("A1").Value = fNameCell.Value
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

May need to tweak this, depending on where your data is.  I am assuming "Obama" could be any text, that is three columns right of column D, where "First Name:" is found.

Comment: You may need to `FindNext` too - I think there are multiple instances of "Unit Name"...

Comment: @BigBen - Ah, good point. I will wait for comment on OP where he wants the "next" name.  I assume Sheet1 A2?

Comment: I have 100 Unit Names and 100 worksheets. will it work for all of them?

Comment: Looks like each found value gets pasted on a separate sheet (?) - `Sheets(m).Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`...

Comment: yes each value gets separate sheet.https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben

Comment: @ReskaBu "@BigBen" works fine instead of that link :)

Comment: @BigBen I am Lazy:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub Shift_Over5()
Dim i As Long
'Sheet name should be a string
Dim SheetName As String
Dim FirstName As Range
Dim UnitName As Range
'Dim l As Byte --> I changed it to lUnitSheetLastrow, because we need to copy the data from sheet1 to sheet 1,2...
' then you need to check the last row of unit sheet and write data to the last row + 1.
Dim lUnitSheetLastrow As Long
Dim FirstMatch As Variant

Dim Start
Start = VBA.Timer

For i = 1 To 40000 Step 1
    'For clear code and easy to follow, you need to mention the sheet you want to interact
    'Here i use 'Activesheet', i assume that the current sheet is sheet1
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = "Unit Name" Then
        ' i think we dont need this code line, because we identified the cell in column B has value is "Unit Name"
        'Set UnitName = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Unit Name")
        ' Here you dont need to use Offset
        'SheetName = UnitName.Offset(1, 0).Value
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value
        ' Find "First Name" in 20 rows in column E.
        ' What happen if i<20, the nextline will show the error, because the minimum row is 1
        If i < 40 Then
            Set FirstName = ActiveSheet.Range("D1" & ":D" & i).Find(what:="First Name:")
        Else
            Set FirstName = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i & ":D" & (i + 40)).Find(what:="First Name")
        End If
        ' make sure the SheetName is not empty and Unit sheet is existing in you workbook then copy the first name to  unit sheet
        If SheetName <> "" And CheckWorkSheetAvailable(SheetName) Then
            ' Check the first name is not nothing
            If Not FirstName Is Nothing Then
                'Check if the cell B7 in unit sheet empty or not
                If Worksheets(SheetName).Range("H7").Value = "" Then
                    'if empty, write to B7
                    Worksheets(SheetName).Range("H7").Value = FirstName.Offset(1, 0).Value
                Else
                    'else, Find the lastrow in column D of unit sheet
                    lUnitSheetLastrow = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(Worksheets(SheetName).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    'Write data to lastrow +1
                    Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A" & (lUnitSheetLastrow + 1)).Value = FirstName.Offset(, 1).Value
                End If

            End If

        End If
    'You forgot to put end if here
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print Round(Timer - Start, 3)
End Sub

Function CheckWorkSheetAvailable(SheetName As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = SheetName Then
        CheckWorkSheetAvailable = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function
```

thank you everyone I found the answer.